# Most accurate translation of "possum"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, animales, vocabulario

What is the most universal Spanish word to describe a possum? What regional variations exist? Does the translation refer specifically to the same animal as the English word, or does it cover a larger variety of animals?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the English word already refers to more than one different animal in English. The possums in Australia are not the same as the ones in America.

Comment: This wannabe Latinist saw the headline and immediately thought "puedo!"

Comment: Possum en español es zarigüeya. En algunas partes de Estados Unidos, usan Possum para referirse a la comadreja, pero es un error, ya que su forma en inglés es weasel. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In English, all members of the Order/Family *Didelphimorphia/Didelphidae* are called opossums, and this matches with the general Spanish use of *zarigüeya*.

But in Ecuadorian Spanish, for example, 16 of the 21 native species of opossum have a common name containing *raposa*, and *zarigüeya* is specific to the 2 named species of the Genus *Didelphis* (this includes *the common opossum* - *el zarigüeya común*, which is the only species also native to North America).

Different countries/regions of Central America have their own specific terms for opossums, which may be a general term or a word for certain species which are native to that area:

#### English

- **North America** *opossum*
- **Southern North America** *possum*

#### Spanish

- **Spain (general)** *zarigüeya*
- **Texas** *tacuaches*, *tlacuaches*
- **Latin America (general)** *zorra mochilera*<sup>1</sup>

  - **México** *tlacuache*

    - **Yucatán** *zorro*, *zorra*
  - **Central America (general)** *tlacuache*, *clacuache*, *tacuache*, *tacuacín*<sup>3</sup>

    - **Costa Rica** *zorro*<sup>1</sup>, *zorro pelón*<sup>1</sup>, *zorra*, *tacuacín*
    - **Guatemala** *tacuacín*
    - **El Salvador** *tlacuache*, *tacuazín*, *guasalo*
    - **Honduras** *tlacuache*, *tacuacín*/*tacuazín*, *guasalo*
    - **Nicaragua** *zorro [de] cola pelada*<sup>1</sup>, *tacuacín*, *cuila*
      <sup>2</sup> (Masaya)
    - **Panamá** *tacuacín*, *zorro*, *zorra*
  - **Ecuador** *raposa*<sup>1</sup>, *zorro*
  - **Colombia** *fara*, *chucha*, *zarigüeya*, *runcho*, *raposa*, *zorrochuchos*<sup>4</sup>
  - **Venezuela** *faro*, *churro*, *rabipelado*, *quengue*, *zorro*
  - **Perú** *muca*, *huanchaco*, *canchaluco*
  - **Bolivia** *carachupas*
  - **Paraguay** *comadreja*, *mykurẽ* (guarani)
  - **Uruguay** *comadreja*<sup>1</sup>, *overa*
  - **Argentina** *comadreja*<sup>1</sup>, *overa*

---

**Notas:**

1. <sup>*Raposa* means *fox* in Galicia (*zorro* in most other regions of Spain), but in Ecuador it is the common name for most species of *opossum*.</sup>

   <sup>This polysemy occurred in English terms for newly discovered animals in the Americas too. For example, the *[American Robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_robin)* is actually a type of thrush, the *[American Buffalo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_bison)* is a type of bison, and the *[Pronghorn Antelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronghorn)* is more closely related to giraffes.</sup>

   <sup>Note that *comadreja* means *weasel* in Spain, similar to the co-opting of the terms *zorro* and *raposa*.</sup>
2. <sup>Debería revisarse, pues *cuilo* en Costa Rica es *cuyo* *Cavia porcellus* o *Cavia* cobaya.</sup>
3. <sup>From Nahuatl *tlacuatzin*</sup>

   > <sup>[**tacuacín**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=KslnPSFfMx0AtXv1x00). Del nahua tlacuatzin, bocado sabroso, y este de tlacua, comer</sup>
   >   <sup>[**tlacuache**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=edrNFFXnyx0AgI5EWbV). (Del nahua tlacuatzin, bocado sabroso).</sup>
4. <sup>Specifically the largest species</sup>

---

**Fuentes**:

<sup>• http://wikifaunia.com/mamiferos/zarigueya/</sup>
<sup>• https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opossum#Classification</sup>
<sup>• https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didelphis_marsupialis#Nombres_comunes</sup>
<sup>• https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didelphimorphia#Nombres_comunes</sup>
<sup>• http://zoologia.puce.edu.ec/Vertebrados/mamiferos/ListaEspecies.aspx?Id=159</sup>

Answer (score 11):

Technically, "possum" refers to species of the suborder Phalangeriformes, distributed in Australia. However, "opossums" are also commonly called possums (in America).

So, "Falangero" is correct for "possum", and it's derived from the latin name of the suborder they belong (Phalangeriformes). Anyway, I guess possums are not quite common animals. For "opossum" the spanish word is "zarigüeya". "Zarigüeyas" are common and well known animals in America (only american marsupials). So, it depends on what animal are you really referring to.

Anyway, I think "posum" is totally understandable, and if you check in spanish wikipedia for "posum", you get the correct answer. I just ask to a couple of friends (spanish native speakers too) about the meaning of "Los falangeros viven en Australia" y "Los posums viven en australia". Falangeros in the first sentence isn't uniquely associated with an animal, but posum is.  I also think in some contexts, "falangero" could be easily interpreted as "thief" rather than an unknown animal, for people ignoring the real meaning of the word. Again, it's not a common animal.

Comment: Tlacuache en Mexico

Answer (score 5):

My Larousse Gran Diccionario lists two Spanish words for the two animals refereed to as "possum" in English:

> 1. *US (opossum)* zarigüeya *f*; IDIOM *Fam* **to play possum** *(pretend to be asleep)* hacerse el dormido/la dormida; *(pretend to know nothing)* hacerse el sueco/la sueca
> 2. *Austr (marsupial)* falangero *m*

Answer (score 2):

I found this on [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/baby-opossum.2249664/) (original source [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didelphimorphia#Nombres_comunes)):

> El principal nombre común que reciben los didelfimorfos es el de
>   **zarigüeyas**; además, son conocidos en El Salvador como **tacuazines**, en
>   Guatemala como **tacuacines**, en México como **tlacuaches** o **tacuaches**, en
>   Ecuador como **guanchacas**, en Honduras como **guasalos**, en el Perú como
>   **mucas** o **canchalucos**, en Bolivia como **carachupas**, en Colombia como
>   **faras**, **chuchas**, **runchos** o **raposas**, en Venezuela como **rabipelados** o
>   **faros**, en Costa Rica, Panamá y algunas partes de México (como Yucatán)
>   como **“zorros”**, y en Uruguay y Argentina como **“comadrejas” overas**,
>   aunque estos dos últimos términos son equívocos, ya que comparten el
>   nombre con mamíferos placentarios completamente diferentes.

Answer (score 2):

`Cuila`, in Nicaragua

that might be a regionalism only.   my wife is from Masaya.   I always forget the Mexican word, which brought me to this site

Answer (score 2):

I used to work with a Mexican chef who called me 'tlacuache.' I didn't know what it meant and he didn't know how to say it in English. "Rata grande" was as close as I got. Further research revealed little until I asked a waitress at Hooters. 
"Tlacuache is a possum" she thought it was hilarious and gave me some Spanish words to throw back at the chef next time.

Answer (score 1):

"**Rabipelado**" en **Venezuela**.

> Especie: [Didelphis
>   albiventris](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didelphis_albiventris)
>   Lund, 1840 (Faro, Rabipelado de los andes o de orejas blancas)
>   Especie: [Didelphis
>   marsupialis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didelphis_marsupialis)
>   Linnaeus, 1758 (Rabipelado común o de orejas negras, Quengue, Churro,
>   Faro, Yaguare)